# How do I reference cell dynamically in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I need to combine string values from (fixed column, variable row) + (fixed column, fixed row) how do I do this?

for example:

```
      |    ONE       |      TWO     |  THREE
ONE   |  ONE-ONE     |  TWO-ONE     | THREE-ONE     
TWO   |  ONE-TWO     |  TWO-TWO     | THREE-TWO 
THREE |  ONE-THREE   |  TWO-THREE   | THREE-THREE*
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming top is row one and left is column A for your example, put the following in B2 drag across and down to fill the array.

```
=CONCATENATE(B$1,"-",$A2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I got this far but not sure on how to make it into a formula so it works for all other cells.

Comment: This formula works to fill in the range for the example you provided. After you enter the formula in the top left cell, you should be able to click the bottom right corner and drag to the right to fill across the columns in the top row. After filling in the top row, click the bottom right corner of that top right cell with the top row highlighted and drag down to fill the rows. If this isn't what you need than you need to expand on your question.